# What does apache error 101 mean?

Tags: apache-http-server

I'm seeing an inexplicable error message in my Apache2 `error_log` file.

```
[Tue Apr 15 12:34:14 2014] [error] [client 192.168.100.2] 101
[Tue Apr 15 12:34:14 2014] [error] [client 192.168.100.2] 101
[Tue Apr 15 12:34:14 2014] [error] [client 192.168.100.2] 101
```

It seems to always appear in groups of three.  I have looked at the CGI that is being hit (which is returning `304`) and it appears that the error does not show up in the log until it has finished running.

This is very reproducable for a given page, and from any browser.  I reload the browser and every time I reload I see this in the log.  There isn't any discernible effect in the output, that is, there is no indication that anything is going wrong.  I have also seen that sometimes I get a "referer" entry after the number, e.g.

```
[Tue Apr 15 12:34:14 2014] [error] [client 192.168.100.2] 101, referer: https://...
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Can you replicate it at will?  Does it matter which browser you use?

Comment: Yes. No. Updated my question.